# Can a Lipschitz continuous function be strongly convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $\varphi:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$, and suppose for all $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$,
$$\|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)\|\leq L\|x-y\|$$
 for Lipschitz constant $L$. Is it possible for such a function to satisfy strong convexity? i.e.,
$$
\varphi(x) - \varphi(y) \geq \nabla \varphi(y)^T(x-y) + \frac{\lambda}{2}\|x-y\|^2
$$
I can't think of such an example, so I'm curious if there is a proof to show this.

Comment: What happens when $n=1?$

Comment: Is there something particular to see in that case? The question arises because we often work with strongly convex functions with Lipschitz gradients, but I am curious what happens with only Lipschitz continuity.

Comment: A slight correction on your top inequality: you should use $|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)|$, not $\|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)\|$.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible for a strongly convex function to have a Lipschitz continuous *gradient*, but no, it is not possible for a strongly convex function to have a Lipschitz continuous *value*. To see why, note that
$$\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)\geq \nabla\varphi(y)^T(x-y)+\frac{\lambda}{2}\|x-y\|^2 \geq \left(\frac{\lambda}{2}\|x-y\|-\|\nabla\varphi(y)\|_*\right)\|x-y\|$$
where $\|\cdot\|_*$ is the norm dual to $\|\cdot\|$. This follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$-\|u\|_*\|v\|\leq u^Tv\leq\|u\|_*\|v\|.$$ Therefore, for $x\neq y$, we have
$$\frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)}{\|x-y\|} \geq -\|\nabla\varphi(y)\|_*+\frac{\lambda}{2}\|x-y\|$$
The right-hand side is unbounded as $\|x-y\|\rightarrow+\infty$, so no fixed value of $L$ can be found.

Comment: Could you please give me a reference for the first fact? I'm interested in the equivalence of being strongly convex and having Lipschitz differential